# How to structure controllers for a model that must be presented in several ways?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model-view-controller

Suppose there's a `Photos` model. For this model I have several views: recent photos, popular photos, favourite photo etc.. How do I go about creating the controller for this model. There are different options:

1. One `PhotosController` with an `index` action. I send a parameter to the index action and based on this parameter the controller makes a query to the DB and returns `@photos` to the view. This has the disadvantage that the `index` action will become quite big.
2. Same as above but logic for deciding what query to make is extracted into a service, so that the controller stays lean.
3. One `PhotosController` with several actions `recent`, `popular`, `favorite` etc., but that's not very restful.
4. Several controllers with `index` actions - `RecentPhotosController`, `PopularPhotosController` etc.. In that case though I must still have a normal `PhotosController` to hande `show`, `edit` actions.

Is there an established best practice for this and what are the considerations when choosing one of those options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go way 1.

The controller should not grow big: you must create the query out of it from params in a service object.

Something like:

```
def index 
  @photos = PhotoQuery.new(params).call
  #....
end

class PhotoQuery
  attr_reader :params
  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def call
    case params[:type]
    when 'recent' then Photo.recent
    else Photo.all
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: OK, that sounds good. One further question though - how do I pass the parameter to the index action. I imagine to have a menu with links to the different lists and the links will be constructed with something like `photos_path(sort_type: 'recent')`. So the parameters will be hard coded in the links. Is this the correct way?